Airflow Plugin: Proper way to define a custom model in the metadata Postgres database?
In Airflow Plugins, what is the proper way to define a custom model for storing plugin specific data in airflow's Postgres metadata database?
I've tried the approach in this post: Airflow Plugin - create own model and use airflow metadatabase for storing plugin specific data
But it doesn't seem to work.
I've come up with this solution, but I don't think this is the best way to implement this...:
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from airflow.utils.db import provide_session
from airflow.models.base import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

class Custom(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'custom'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    description = Column(String(255))

@provide_session
def create_custom_table(session=None):
    engine = session.get_bind()
    Custom.__table__.create(engine, checkfirst=True)

# Define the plugin
class CustomPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = 'custom_plugin'
    
    def on_load(self, *args, **kwargs):
        create_custom_table()

